# Filtering IP in google analytics

Tags: filter, ip, analytics

I want to make a filter to exclude internal traffic of a company. Should I use public IPs or not? I ve got a large range of IPs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use the public IP address, and then use regex to filter the ranges. (Friendly reminder to post coding questions only to this forum.)